# CSS problem in ie, ff

Tags: javascript, css

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

 * {
  border:      0;
  margin:      0;
  padding:     0;
  outline:     none;
 }
 body {
  background-color:   #5e0305;
/*  font-family:    'Helvetica','Arial';*/
  font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:     12px;
  color:      #999;
  line-height:    16px;

  }



 #itrunk, #strunk {
/*  width:auto; 
  width:1260px;*/
   height:      62px;
 }

 .wrapper {
  width:      1000px;
  margin:      0 auto;
  }

 #topbar {

  height:      62px;
  overflow:      visible;
  position:     relative;
  z-index:     3;
 }

 #topbar #itmlogo {
  float:      left;
  list-style:     none; 
 /* display:     block;*/
  }

 #topbar #menuTop { /* only for box containing menutop items*/
  float:      right;
  height:      55px;
  background-color:   transparent;
 }

 #topbar ul#menuTop {
  list-style:     none;
 }

 #topbar ul#menuTop li {
  float:      left;
  text-align:     right;
 }
 #topbar ul#menuTop a {
  float:      left;
  display:     block;
  width:      110px;
  height:      42px;
  padding:     14px 7px 0px 0px;
  text-transform:    uppercase;
  text-decoration:   none;
  font-weight:    bold;
  font-size:     12px;
  color:      #000;
  letter-spacing:    1px;
 }


.ddpanel {
 position:     relative;
 top:      0px;
 left:      0px;
 z-index:     2;
 min-width:     1000px;
 height   auto; 

 background-color:    pink;
 border-color:    #FFFF00;
 border-style:    solid;
 border-width:    1px;
 padding-bottom:    20px;
}

.ddpanel .ddpanelcontent {
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #fff; 
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #fff;
 position:      relative;
 top:       0px;
 margin:       0 auto;
 padding:      20px 25px 20px 25px;
 clear:       both;
 width:       942px;

 z-index:      2;

 border-color:     #FFFFFF;
 border-style:     solid;
 border-width:     2px;
 color:       #336666;
 font-size:      12px;
 font-weight:     500;
 font-variant:     normal;
 letter-spacing:     0.05em;
 line-height:      30px;


 background-color:    #CCCCCC;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:  25px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 25px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
 border-top-left-radius:   25px;
 border-top-right-radius:  25px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:  25px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:  25px; 

-webkit-border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;
}





-->
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="strunk" >




<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="topbar">


      <div id="menubox">
        <ul id="menuTop">
          <li>
     <a onclick="getLink('home'); return false"  onmouseover="status=''; return true;" >home
     </a>
         </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- topbar-->


  </div>


<div class="wrapper"><!-- wrapper1 open-->
<div id="mypanel" class="ddpanel">
<div id="mypanelcontent" class="ddpanelcontent">

<span id="text1" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:600">What services do we offer ?</span><br /><span id="text2" style="font-size:13px; font-weight:500;">
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
</span>

</div> <!-- mypanelcontent-->
</div><!-- mypanel -->
</div> <!-- wrapper1 closed-->
</div><!-- strunk-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) is a great place to set up demos for things like this

Comment: I doubt anybody will be able to help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Wrap your question in a code element, and give us a description of the problem.

Comment: LOL! First time I've seen SO layout break like this..

Comment: great code, what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Add `<!DOCTYPE>` on top of your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```